# Glitchy symbols on my monitor (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I have started to get these weird glitchy symbols on my monitors. I have tried a restart but after a little while they came back. They flash on and off occasionally. The issue does not only overlay chrome but also plex and just general windows.

[image: Glitchy icons overlapping windows]

Comment: I'm afraid your graphics card is toast.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Can you see them in a screenshot, or only 'live' on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out my GPU gave it a good clean and rebooted and the problem got a little worse. I then tested using a cheap GPU I borrowed and it works fine. Looks like my GPU is busted. It is 6 years old after all. I will be buying a new one it looks like. Thanks for the comments :)